# Pass Props to a modal in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, attributes, modal-dialog, vue-component

i am struggling trying to pass my props value to my modal.
Above my JS code end below my HTML

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdUzI.png)

When i try to get the ID of the post using this.$props.id, the result is the last id on the page, not the ID related to the post.

I do not know how to pass the ID from the homepage to the modal.

thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

I think the below reference will help you to send props to the component

https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-use-props-to-pass-data-to-child-components/

Comment: ok thank you! Not sure i will handle it but I will try

Comment: Link-only answers are not a good idea. If the link fails in the future, your answer will be useless for others. As a safety measure, quote the relevant parts of the link in your answer.